# PDF not download - FPDF

Tags: php, download, fpdf

I used FPDF library to download pdf using php.

[viewinspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYKqX.png)

This views in preview and response tab.. but didn't download.

This is my code

```
        $file = 'File.pdf';
       
        ob_clean();

        $pdf = new FPDF();

        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $pdf->SetMargins(2, 2, 2);

        $pdf->WriteHTML($post['txt']);
  
        $pdf->Output('I',$file);
        exit;
```

Comment: Don't use AJAX. And use `D` for destination.

Answer (score 0):

Use "D" parameter instead.
"I" parameter will send the file inline to the browser.
So your code should:

```
    $pdf->Output('D',$file);
```

Comment: I used, still the same

Comment: You can set header manually before:     $pdf->Output('D',$file); by adding         header("Content-type:application/pdf"); 
         header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='$file'");